# Video stream is not playing in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, byte, partial

Video stream is not working with partial content byte streaming web API.

```swift
let headerFields:[String: String] = ["Range":"bytes"]

let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url:url, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headerFields])

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)

self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Comment: Try `self.player.play()`?

Comment: Yes I used play() but this is still not working. My web API returns data as partial content. Web API is in Node. I used streaming AF.streamRequest and after all data completely streaming and save video data locally then I am able to play video. But I wanted play data parallel stream buffering